# tag cloud styling

Tags: css

I'm trying to style [my blog's tag cloud](http://festivals.ie/blog/index) as [described here](http://calebogden.com/advanced-css-tags/). I've followed the instructions, but there is one small problem. I can't seem to figure out how to change the white section of each tag (circled in red below) to be transparent such that the shaded background shows through.

[image]

Comment: I guess you can't with this technique. It depends on actually covering the orange with white if I get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works because the background of the demo page is white. The below CSS is where this color is set:

```
.cloud .tag:before {
    border-color: #FFF transparent;
```

The easiest way would be to change the `#FFF` to a color that best matches the background. You can't just set it as transparent because the tag (yellow/orange thing) is a box and this simply makes a triangle on the left side of that box with different left borders to give it an arrow like look.

See, here I changed it to `transparent #000` to illustrate how it makes the arrow.

[image]

You can't even tell if you change it from `#FFF` to `#EEE`.

```
border-color: #eee transparent;
```

[image]